# How to check if ion-input is not empty?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I cannot use `required`attribute as the ion-input (email) field is conditionally required. Also I do not want to check everytime the form is submitted to fire *invalid email* unless and until the email (ion-input) has some text input and it is not a valid email.
This is what I've done so far:

```
<ion-item >
    <ion-label stacked>{{'email' | translate}}</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="email" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid':(AddContactForm.submitted && email.invalid && addContactData.phone_type=='Email') || (AddContactForm.submitted && email.length && email.invalid)}"  email name="email" [required]="addContactData.phone_type=='Email'"  [(ngModel)]="addContactData.email" value="" class="nui-text-field__input"
       #email="ngModel"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<span class="nui-text-field__sub-label error" *ngIf="(AddContactForm.submitted && email.invalid && addContactData.phone_type=='Email') || (AddContactForm.submitted && email.length && email.invalid)">{{'email_required_validation' | translate}}</span>
```

Comment: with reavtive form validation it should be possible to trigger an event if the conditions are met. check [link](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/10/angular-6-reactive-forms-validation-example) for reference.. if you require the e-mail conditionally then you have to write your own validator I think

Comment: I cannot use reactive forms tbh in this project. But thanks. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a model and check that.

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="this.thing"></ion-input>
```

Then check if `this.thing` is valid :)